# Unable to get ISODate format result

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using MongoCursor to iterate over a collection and to retrieve changeDate (in ISODate format). However, using mongocursor returns the data in a different format. Is it possible to retrieve the changeDate in ISODate format.

Here is the document structure and my code. Please let me know how i can retrieve date in ISODate format.

```
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = col.find().iterator();

        while (cursor.hasNext()) {

            Document doc = hCursor.next();
            Object changeDate = doc.getDate("ChangeDate");
            System.out.println(changeDate);
        }
```

changeDate is returned in the format: **Wed May 05 18:46:58 EDT 2017**

Structure of collection data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("590a253fe4b05069ea21776b"),
    "changeDate" : ISODate("2017-05-03T18:46:58.577Z"),
    "createdBy" : “abc”,
    "lastChangedBy" : “xyzzy”

}
```

I want the output as 2017-05-03T18:46:58.577Z.
I tried using joda date but didn't find it very useful.
Appreciate any help!!

Comment: What is your java version ?

Comment: Java 8, Mongo java driver - 3.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `Date` to `Instant` and `toString()`. Uses the `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT

```
 Date changeDate = doc.getDate("ChangeDate");
 String instant = changeDate.toInstant().toString(); // 2017-05-03T18:46:58.577Z
```